# Override AdminProductsController

Tags: prestashop

I have problem with my custom presta shop module. My module adds new field to product, field name is promotion, is a string. If i add a new product or edit existing i have no problem, i see my new field. But when i have add this field to products list then i don't see this him.

My module:

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

class OverrideTraining extends Module
{
    private $_html = '';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'overridetraining';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0';
        $this->author = 'Pawel Cyrklaf';
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => '1.7.9.9');

        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Override Training');
        $this->description = $this->l('Task to learn override');
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function install()
    {
        if (!parent::install() OR
            !$this->alterProductTable() OR
            !$this->registerHook('displayAdminProductsExtra'))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        if (!parent::uninstall() OR
            !$this->alterProductTable('remove'))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $method
     * @return bool
     */
    public function alterProductTable($method = 'add')
    {
        if ($method == 'add')
            $sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product ADD `promotion` VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL';
        else
            $sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product DROP COLUMN `promotion`';

        if (!Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public function hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra($params)
    {
        $promotion = Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT promotion FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product WHERE id_product = ' . (int)Tools::getValue('id_product'));
        $this->context->smarty->assign('promotion', $promotion);
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'adminProductsExtra.tpl'); 
    }
}
```

and AdminProductsController which i override

```
<?php

class AdminProductsController extends AdminProductsControllerCore
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->fields_list['promotion'] = array(
            'title' => $this->l('Promotion'),
            'align' => 'text-center',
            'class' => 'fixed-width-sm',
            'orderby' => false
        );
    }
}
```

What i do wrong? I have a nemo's course, on his video all works fine, but at me not working this same code.

Comment: Did you try to remove var\cache\dev\class_index.php file?

Comment: @AlexanderGrosul Hi :) No i didn't, i always uninstall and reinstall module, but i will try remove this file.

Comment: @AlexanderGrosul I tried remove but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on adminOrdersController, an i solved by passing a calback for the value to print try to edit your override by adding 'filter_key' and a 'calback'

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->fields_list['promotion'] = array(
            'title' => $this->l('Promotion'),
            'align' => 'text-center',
            'class' => 'fixed-width-sm',
            'filter_key' => 'a!promotion', // syntax: table_alias!field_name
            'callback' => 'displayPromotion'
        );
    }

    public function displayPromotion($value) {
        return $value ;   
    }
```

filter key must be popolated by the alias of the table and with the name of the field that you want to show.

To know what you have to pass as string in filter_key you should check the executed query that show the products in backoffice.

into callback function you can manage or do everything you want with the value before it'll be printed.

To make Prestashop know that there ia a new fields into product table, you have also to override the Product Core class in /classes/product.php

in this file you have to add this `public $promotion;` just below row 293

then you have to edit `the public static $definition = array()` of the product table introducing the definition of your new field, so you have to put into definition array this

```
'promotion' => array(
                'type' => self::TYPE_STRING,
                'lang' => true, // or false if don't need to translate this field
                'validate' => 'isCleanHtml',
                'size' => 255
            ),
```

now your field should be visible in backoffice product list

Comment: Hi :) all works fine for prestashop 1.6, but I using 1.7 :D Of course your answer is good for presta 1.6

Comment: I have 1:1 with your code, and at my me not working. i.e.  promotion field not showing

Comment: Is your promotion fields on ps_product table or in other table which is queryed to show product list in backoffice? or is  part of a your custom table? turn on the debug mode to see any errors

Comment: ok , try to also override the Product Class by adding a public variable named $promotion and update the definition by adding your new field specs. you can find product class into /classes/Product.php

Comment: Yes, promotion field is on ps_product, i can save and update this field for all  products. But i can'f show gim on products list. On my first post you see my complete module code.

Comment: read again my answer i update it with how to override Product Core Class to let Prestashop add your custom filed into his ps_product structure

Comment: This is my full source code https://github.com/PawelCyrklaf/presta-override i have override Product class and rest of your code.